# pr2_teleop problem

Tags: gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i following the Working with Gazebo over ROS tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/WorkingWithGazeboOverRos)

and when i'll run

rosmake pr2_teleop

i obtain [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

And if i run:
roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch

i obtain
[pr2_teleop] is not a package or launch file name

Someone could helpme with that?...

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47467/pr2_teleop-problem/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which ros distro are you using? Please make sure you have a look at [this page](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) and follow the guidelines.

Assuming you are using ros fuerte, try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-apps
```

It will install pr2_teleop.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-05**:
ros fuerte in 12.04 ubuntu, it works, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-apps`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1